# C# MVC run scheduled method?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, scheduled-tasks

i was requested to write a 'syncing' function, i think it means updating the target object every once in a while? so i am wondering what is in C# MVC for running a scheduled method? Thanks a lot.

Comment: atleast show what you have tried (code) Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to give us more information. What are you trying to achieve esactly?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following tutorial for SignalR : http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

I think this is what you need to implement

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if SingalR is the correct answer (per dlght's answer - you don't give us much to go on), but the first thing that comes to mind for scheduled tasks for me is a console/service application that's driven from the windows task scheduler on the server.

Both approaches are very different and are used in very different contexts.  Without some more context in what you actually need, you're not likely to get detailed answers.